# How to add option to javascript RegExp object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a regular expression with a variable, which is dynamically passed.

```
new RegExp("(" + variable_name + ":\\((.*?)\\))");
```

It perfectly results in `/(ABC:\((.*?)\))/`   (if variable_name is ABC)

But, If I pass an option as

`new RegExp("(" + variable_name + ":\\((.*?)\\))") + "g"`,

it gives me the regular expression in string format

`"/(ABC:\((.*?)\))/g"`

and the match() function fails. Is there any good way to pass option without converting the expression into string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. Great answer to a silly question. :(

Comment: Don't have necessary reputation to upvote all answers. :-|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `g` (global modifier) within the brackets.

```
new RegExp("(" + variable_name + ":\\((.*?)\\))", "g");
```

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```
new RegExp("(" + variable_name + ":\\((.*?)\\))", "g");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include whatever option you need:

```
var options = "g"; //g, m, i, or combination of them
new RegExp("(" + variable_name + ":\\((.*?)\\))", options);
```

Hope it's useful!